# What Wordpress / PHP-based template language uses the form <# {{ variable }} #>?

Tags: php, wordpress

I found the following code being output in the HTML source by a Wordpress plugin (Visual Composer). I've having problems with the plugin and want to know:

what is the name of the templating / pre-processor language, so I can research it.

```
<# if ('content' === param_name) { #>
  <span class="vc_content">Content</span>
  <input type="text" style="display: none;" name="param_name" value="{{ param_name }}" placeholder="Required value" class="vc_param-name" data-system="true">
  <span class="description" style="display: none;">Use only letters, numbers and underscore.</span>
<# } else { #>
  <input type="text" name="param_name" value="{{ param_name }}" placeholder="Required value" class="vc_param-name">
  <span class="description">Please use only letters, numbers and underscore.</span>
<# } #>
```

Comment: Dunno why anyone's voting to close this as unclear or too broad.  It's simply asking "what language is this?"

Comment: It looks like a client side template engine to me, the best way to determine is looking in the Network panel of your browser's developer tools and see which .js files are being loaded and determine what template engine that is. There are a lot of template engines that use the {{ }} to output variables and also I've used engines that let you customize the start and end "<# #>" characters.